# How to get an array's value from a JSON object by using Volley?

Tags: android, json

i have json result like this

right know my code in andorid studio going like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrwdw.jpg)

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("response");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");
                        for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject coba = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String namapoli = coba.getString("namapoli");
                            mTextViewResult.append(namapoli);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

but why the app not display the result? anyone can give me  please

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get list array from api response instead of object that you define to get response body from api response:

Change :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("list");
```

To:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("list");
```

and final view will look like this:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject("response");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("list");
                        for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject coba = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String namapoli = coba.getString("namapoli");
                            mTextViewResult.append(namapoli);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

Comment: thank  you for the respond sir, but still nothing happen when i click the button, and no error too..

Comment: @mugen_nanta can you check if it is showing error stack? otherwise code is fine.

Comment: sorry..the code just fine..and its work... thank you very much sir

Comment: @mugen_nanta good to hear that, can you make answer as accepted